# Make a folder show a webpage in amazon s3

Tags: html, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is there a way to make a folder in amazon s3 show a html page?  I have it setup so you can go to a file without .html, for example example.com/testpage(remove .html here).  That works well, but if I did example.com/testpage/ it will not work, because of the extra /.  Is there a way to make the folder with the / at the end show the webpage?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This is generally not a good idea, from a security perspective. However, I think it might be possible if you are using Static Website Hosting. Do you know whether you have that activated on your bucket?

Comment: Yes I have static web hosting enabled.  How is it a bad idea from a security perspective?

Comment: Actually, in playing around, I could get a bucket listing on the raw bucket (not using the static website URL), but only on the root level. The listing came back as XML.